# Clear Powershell Streams in C#

Tags: c#, shell, powershell

I have 3 commands for powershell:

```
            shell.AddScript("Exit-PSSession");
            shell.AddScript("Invoke-Command -ComputerName something -ScriptBlock {some command}");
            shell.AddScript("Invoke-Command -ComputerName something -ScriptBlock {another command}");
```

Now I don't need any response from the first two, but I need the error log from the third one. Because I can't foresee how many errors may occur, I want to clear the `shell` from at least all error messages, better would be a complete empty `shell`.

My solution was this:

```
            shell.AddScript("Exit-PSSession");
            shell.AddScript("Invoke-Command -ComputerName something -ScriptBlock {some command}");
            shell.Invoke();
            shell.Streams.ClearStreams();
            shell.AddScript("Invoke-Command -ComputerName something -ScriptBlock {another command}");
```

But somehow `ClearStreams` does nothing at all, `shell` still knows all old errors and the two previous commands.

The Microsoft sides don't give any more informati0on, than that this method exists and should clear out the `shell`. ([Microsoft Help for ClearStreams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psdatastreams.clearstreams(v=vs.85).aspx)) or [Microsoft Help for streams in general](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psdatastreams(v=vs.85).aspx)

Did I miss something, or am I misunderstanding what they

(Powershell is Version 5.0) and C# runs 4.6 NET Framework

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: `ClearStreams` only clear streams for given `PowerShell` instance. It do nothing with attached PowerShell `Runspace` (`shell.Runspace`). In particular, it do nothing with `$Error` variable or history in that `Runspace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this:

> powershell.Streams.Error();

Sample:

```
PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
powershell.Runspace = CreateRunSpace.runspace;
var exec = "Set-Mailbox -Identity John -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true -ForwardingSMTPAddress 'manuel@contoso.com'";
powershell.AddScript(exec);
powershell.Streams.Error.Clear();
powershell.Streams.Warning.Clear();
var result = powershell.Invoke();
MessageBox.Show(powershell.Streams.Error.Count().ToString()+" error counts");

foreach (var errorRecord in powershell.Streams.Error)
{
MessageBox.Show(errorRecord.ToString()+"first - error");
}
```

Requesting you to post the full script. What kind of object shell is. I think it will have a method as **.Clear()**

NOte: I got this :

> sh.Commands.AddScript("Add-PSSnapin
>   Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager"); sh.Invoke();
>   sh.Commands.Clear();

Could you please check that

Comment: If you are using `Type: System.Management.Automation.PowerShell` , then you can clear it

Comment: Ok I see my problem now, I already tried `shell.Streams.Error.Clear();`, but since I didn't use `Commands.Clear()` as well, the same commands got invoked again, making it seemed like `shell.Streams.Error.Clear();` being without effect.
Thanks

Comment: Ah... That happens sometimes to me too :) @Etaila